# Placing objects without sliding

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have two cuboids (which are rigid-bodies) and I want to arrange them in this way:

[image]

But they just slide away, and I am unable to stop the sliding. I tried increasing friction for both the objects and the ground to be maximum, but to no avail.

How should I stop the sliding?

Note: As in the discussion in the comments, the blocks slide when I set the simulation speed to *6*, but do not slide when it has the usual value of *1*.

My .blend file:
[image]

Comment: I've built a scene like that and it immediately worked with all default settings, without changing friction or anything. Then I changed the _Collisions Shape_ to _Box_ instead of the default  _Convex Hull_ and the cuboids started sliding. But setting the friction up to 1 on all objects stopped them from doing that, too. So maybe it depends on how you've set them up in detail, the angle they have, the distance to each other etc.

Comment: Mine are more ot less directly touching each other at the start of the animation and playing the animation let's them sink into each other a bit. But if you go to _Sensitivity_ > _Collision Margin_ and activate it, with the default value of 0.04 they are now "exploding" away from each other. But setting it very low e.g. 0.0001, they stay together.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, thank you for for answering! My simulation needs to be fast, so I the *Speed* of the Rigid Body World is set to *6*. But, surprisingly, when the simulation speed is *1*, the objects do not slide!

Comment: Not really surprising  ;)  The faster it is, the more inaccurate the simulation can become. So in order to keep the speed at 6, you may try to increase _Substeps per Frame_ and _Solver Iterations_ in the _Scene Properties_. This can help make simulations more accurate, actually even at slower speeds the simulation behaves differently when calculated in more precision. But the speed change might be an information to be put in a question like yours to help spotting the problem.

Comment: Increasing *Substeps Per Frame* worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try turning down the *Collision Margin*. You may also want to ensure that they have some mass.
The distance setting is found under *Rigid Body* > *Sensitivity* the mass is under *Rigid Body* > *Settings*.
You will need to adjust the collision margin by checking that box then turning it down. You might also change the *Collision Shape* to *Box*.

Comment: Where is the option for changing *Collider Distance*?

Comment: @CoolCoder It's called _Collision Margin_, see my comments under your question.

Comment: I don't think that the _Collision Margin_ was too high before, since he doesn't know where to find the setting it was disabled anyway which makes it very low, namely zero.